# Adding noise to dummy variables

Tags: r, regression, knn, dummy-variable

I am trying to run a knn regression, however, I have a lot of dummy variables and therefore a lot of ties. To solve this problem, I want to add noise to the dummies. So I want to give the rows with 1 on a specific variable a random value between 1 and 0.99. I want to do the same for rows with a zero value, but then give them a random number between 0 and 0.01. Can somebody help me with an efficient way to transform my dummy variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an  `ifelse` statement to transform your dummy vars:

```
set.seed(4)
df <- data.frame(letter=letters[1:10],dummy=sample(0:1,10,replace = T))
df$newdummy <- ifelse(df$dummy==1,runif(1,0.99,1),runif(1,0,0.01))
```

Here I add a new column, but you can substitute the existing one by assigning the `ifelse` statement to the old dummy variable.
However, I agree with the answer of @SamR, about dummy variables. It is not very clear what you want to do with the dummy variable

Answer (score 3):

There is a great function in base R for this called `jitter`.

```
jitter(x = c(rep(0, 10), rep(1, 10)), factor = 0.01)
```

Answer (score 0):

To just add noise you can do something like:

```r
x  <- rep(1, 1000)
noisy_x  <- x + rnorm(n = 1000, mean = 0, sd = 0.000001)
noisy_x
#  [1] 1.0000010 1.0000004 1.0000014 0.9999998 0.9999998 1.0000007 0.9999990 1.0000006 1.0000006 0.9999989 1.0000007 0.9999998 0.9999992 1.0000002 0.9999989 0.9999994
#   [17] 0.9999987 0.9999997 1.0000000 0.9999993 1.0000000 0.9999997 1.0000013 0.9999991 0.9999987 0.9999994 0.9999983 0.9999992 0.9999982 1.0000004 1.0000000 1.0000009
```

However, I would question whether this is the right approach. Dummy variables do not usually need noise added to them. What do you mean you are getting ties? In general, if you have a variable representing *n* levels of a factor, you will only need *n-1* dummy variables. Is this what you are referring to?

Comment: Thank you I am going to try this. No, I mean because I am running a KNN regression with a lot of dummy variables I get ties. Therefore I want to try adding noise so that the ties are resolved.

Comment: It's probably more for cross validated than here but I am not sure that this is a great approach - your ties may be broken but not meaningfully (i.e. only by randomness). Have you thought about using correspondence analysis or a similar to recode your categorical variables?